# CalendarView doesn't show when visabilty is initally set to GONE

Tags: android, kotlin, calendarview

**UPDATE: I added my whole code after I fixed it as I stated in my answer**

hello guys I am having a weird bug. I have a calendar view that's initially set to GONE and I try to change it to VISIBLE and GONE when the user clicks on an icon.
it doesn't show.

but, when I set it initially to VISIBLE it works as expected.

I tried debugging and it enters both branches of the when statement, but it doesn't change the visibility 
any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
calendar_icon.setOnClickListener {
            when (calendarView.visibility) {
                View.GONE -> {
                    calendarView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                else -> { calendarView.visibility = View.GONE

                }
            }
        }
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/per_day_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/brighter_white">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/brighter_white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp"
        app:contentPadding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/per_day_search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:textColorHint="@color/silver"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView11"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_azure_bg"
                android:padding="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_line" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_lavendar_bg"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calendarView"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/per_day_current_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/calendar_icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_calendar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/report_item_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/periwinkle"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/user_name"
            android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/report_item_attend"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/platinum"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/attend_time"
            android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/report_item_leave"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/misty_rose"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/leave_time"
            android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/report_item_lost_points"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/magnolia"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/lostPoints"
            android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/report_rv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout5" />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment code

```
package iti.intake40.mawgood_admin.reports.per_day

import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import iti.intake40.mawgood_admin.R
import iti.intake40.mawgood_admin.core.DateUtilities
import iti.intake40.mawgood_admin.models.Report
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_reports.*

class ReportsFragment : Fragment(), ReportPerDayContract.IView {

    private val TAG = ReportsFragment::class.java.simpleName
    private lateinit var presenter: ReportPerDayPresenter
    private lateinit var adapter: ReportPerDayAdapter
    private val reportList = ArrayList<Report>()
    private var rootView: View? = null
    private var mDatePickerDialog: DatePickerDialog? = null
    private var per_day_current_date: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reports, container, false)
        per_day_current_date = root.findViewById(R.id.per_day_current_date)
        presenter = ReportPerDayPresenter(context!!, this)
        return root
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        rootView = view.findViewById(R.id.per_day_root)

        presenter.getOrganizationCreationDate()
        calendarView.maxDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
        calendarView.visibility = View.GONE
        calendar_icon.setOnClickListener {
            when (calendarView.visibility) {
                View.GONE -> {
                    calendarView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                View.VISIBLE -> {
                    calendarView.visibility = View.GONE

                }
            }
        }

        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
            calendarView.visibility = View.GONE
            val date = "$dayOfMonth-${month + 1}-$year"
            Log.d(TAG, date)
            val dayInUnix = DateUtilities.convertDateToTimestamp(date)

            presenter.listenForChanges(dayInUnix.toString())
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        activity!!.title = "Reports"
        search()
        per_day_current_date?.text = DateUtilities.getTodayInDate()
        val today = DateUtilities.getTodayInUnix().toString()
        presenter.listenForChanges(today)
    }

    private fun search() {
        per_day_search.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                adapter.filter.filter(s)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        presenter.detachListeners()
    }

    override fun displayNoData() {
//        per_day_empty_iv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
//        per_day_empty_tv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        report_rv.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    override fun hideNoData() {
//        per_day_empty_iv.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
//        per_day_empty_tv.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        report_rv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    override fun updateRecyclerView(reports: List<Report>) {
        reportList.clear()
        reportList.addAll(reports)
        adapter = ReportPerDayAdapter(reportList)

        report_rv.setHasFixedSize(true)
        report_rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        report_rv.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun updateDayView(date: String) {
        per_day_current_date?.text = date
    }

    override fun showConnectionError() {
        Snackbar.make(rootView!!, R.string.no_connection_show_cache, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show()
    }

    override fun setCalendarStartDate(creationDateUnix: Long) {
        calendarView.minDate = creationDateUnix
        Log.d(TAG, creationDateUnix.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Your tiny code snippet seems fine so your issue is likely caused by something else. You would have to post more code (like the layout file and complete fragment / activity) to identify where the issue is. But you should review ALL places where you change that view's visibility.

Comment: updated the question. I added the xml for the fragment.  please check again

Comment: This is still insufficient information. You likely have a logic bug in your code that is somehow / somewhere changing the visibility property. So you need to post the code of the fragment that loads and manipulates this layout, not just the static XML.

Comment: @dominicoder I added the whole fragment code as well. please check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like a bug. I was able to fix this by removing the visibility attribute from XML.
and set the visibility programmatically in `onViewCreated` like this: `calendarView.visibility = View.GONE`